# CTL satisfied by Kripke Structure

Tags: model-checking, software-verification, temporal-logic, computation-tree-logic

given a Kripke Structure I want to check if a CTL formula is satisfied or not. 
the CTL is: $$ AG(c \vee AX\neg E((a\vee b)Uc)) $$
I have read that it is better to write to CTL in terms of $\wedge $ and E so for instance for an inner part  $AX \neg E((a\vee b)Uc) $ I have re-written as: $$ \neg EX\neg(\neg E(\neg(\neg a\wedge\neg b)Uc) $$ 
but it seems to be illegal CTL.

generally what is the best approach for these kinds of problems to solve. re-write the formula in terms of other operations or just draw the parse tree.